# How to upload a Ms Access Database on server?

Tags: ms-access

I am tring to create an Access application. 
I want the database (tables) to be online and the app (forms, reports) to be installed on each pc.

Is there any possible way to succeed this? 
Will I need a dedicated server ?

Alternatively, is there any platform (free or not) that I can upload the whole Access app making it Web app?

I made a research and Sharepoint does not satisfy me at all.
Unfortunately, microsoft does not support Access web apps anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best and most low cost is SharePoint tables from an office 365 plan.

Remember, Access web publishing is NOT required if you migrate tables to SharePoint, and then place the front ends on each PC.

So even the most basic office 365 planes support SharePoint tables. (You don’t need Access web publishing for the SharePoint table feature). You one monthly plan of about $7 allows all 20 users to connect with the one account one $7 fee total for all 20 users.

You can’t use “files” like Access accDB ones over the internet with say OneDrive, or drop box etc. The reason for this is these web systems don’t support windows networking. So while you can pull a word file from such system, you cannot EDIT the file on that remote system. When you are done editing word, then you send the WHOLE file back up to the remote system and the word document is OVERWRITTEN.

Of course with Access, if each user were to OVERWRITE THE WHOLE file, then each user would thus always overwrite anything changed by any other user. So these systems do NOT support the ability to update ONLY BITS AND PARTS of the file. It is this “bits” and “parts” updating that allows two users to work at the same time and edit separate rows of data in the ONE file.

So Access is VERY different than the rest of office.

With word, or Excel, then you edit the document and then SAVE THE WHOLE document. That “saving” will thus overwrite the changes made by anyone else. So these “cloud” systems do NOT support the ability to only update “part” of the file – but only the WHOLE file.

Word, Excel etc. thus work on a “whole file” update model. However, Access requires the “special” ability of the windows file system that allows one to update ONLY PART of the file. And even more important is windows file system allows two people to update at the same time as long as they are updating “different” parts of the file.

What the above means is then you have to move the back end data file from a “file” based system to some kind of server database system. That means MySQL, SQL server, or SharePoint tables.

> I made a research and Sharepoint does not satisfy me at all. Unfortunately, microsoft does not support Access web apps anymore.

I would not write off this choice. Access web publishing is NOT required for Access to use SharePoint tables. And that table option is VERY nice since such tables even work without the internet connection and will “sync” or “catch up” when you finally do get a decent internet connection. In other words this “sync” type of model is more like email then traditional links to a database.

This web based message system and technology is FAR BETTER than Access ODBC tables since “small” connection breaks that is common over the internet tends to make use of ODBC over the internet rather painful compared to SharePoint tables (they were built from the ground up with the internet in mind, while linked ODBC tables in Access were created 25 years ago, and they did not have the internet back then – so the design considerations of internet were not given to the ODBC choice.

I mean, you can make a car fly, but if you design the machine from the ground up as a plane as compared to a car, the result is a far better machine that flies. So there will be 100’s if not 1000’s of small choices made in the design of the product for its given intended use. So Access was around LONG before the internet – so most options don’t play nice over the internet. However the SharePoint table open is from the ground up based on internet connection technology – ones that often break, or even stop working.

I explain the table migration process to office 365 here:

https://youtu.be/3wdjYIby_b0?list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5

The other choice is to migrate the data to the Web hosting database system. Most web sites usually offer MySQL or SQL server as a database choice. However, ONE BIG detail is you have to find a web hosting provider that allows external ODBC connections. Today, less and less web hosting companies allow raw external connections to the database that drives the web site. (The reason of course is security).

So while say when you go to amazon to buy a book, the web site and web server system can pull information about books etc. from the database system. However, you on the outside cannot connect or link access to the database system that drives Amazon.

So while the web hosted server has full use of the database server, you as an external outside user (not from the web site) do not have such permissions.

So you need to find a provider that includes a database server, but in addition to allowing the web site to grab + pull data from database server, they also allow everyone on the planet who is connected to the wild and crazy internet to ALSO be able to connect to the database server (and by-pass the web site).

So as you can see, this is a big security risk because that database server now has to allow any crazy person on the internet to pull data from that database. I mean, I seen within say 5, or 10 minutes of opening up such database systems, you see 100’s if not 1000’s of logon attempts and people trying to link to your exposed tables! I mean, if all your users can link and see those tables, then so can the everyone else on the wild internet. So in a very short time automated bots will attempt to logon and link to those tables if they find someone crazy enough to “open” up their database system to allowing everyone to “link” or at least try to “link” to those tables.

So fewer and fewer web hosting companies allow external connections to the database that by-pass the web site. You need this by-pass the web site and go direct to database ability. The reason of course is Access is not connecting or linking to the web site, but needs to link DIRECTLY to the database system. (This thus has near nothing to do with the web site – you are to consume the database system, not the web system).

As noted, most simple is SharePoint and office 365. And this choice also has good performance WHEN the file sizes are limited and fit within the SharePoint table limits.

Another choice would be to purchase a monthly SQL Azure plan, and then again migrate your data from Access to SQL server. This setup will also work. They have a number of cool security features (you can restrict what IP address are allowed to connect for example).

Last but not least:
Your internet connection is about 10 times, or even 30 times slower than your normal office network. That means a typical wait time of say 3 seconds with your split application now on your office network will become a wait time of 30, or even 150 seconds if you connect over the internet (150 seconds = 2.5 minutes!!!!!).

This means you have to spend time optimizing the application for this setup. I explain this issue here:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html

If you don't think this speed issue outlined in the above wans article does not apply to you then I suggest a re-reading it again and again until such time you realize this slower internet issue applies to you. Do the basic math - your internet connection will be 10 to 100 times slower then your cheap local office network. Do take more meds if you don't grasp this issue and don't think it applies to your case and use - it does.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: Can I ask you something more?? I have read that the maximum size of an Access database is 2GB. What can we do in case we have more data??

Comment: Well, if you using SQL server, then no such limitations exist. So that limit only applies to a accDB file - not when you connect to a server database system. In fact the free edition of SQL server allows up to 10 gigs of data, so even on a single local PC system, you can install + use SQL server as the data store and system for your application and thus get around this limitation. As noted, this file size limitation does not apply when using SQL server with Access.

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternative options to Access Web App is PowerApps. It is one of the foremost suggestion to migrate Access Web Apps which is quite easy and powerful.